# Installing Tensorflow on Mac for PyPy

Tags: python, macos, numpy, tensorflow, pypy

I am able to install tensorflow for python using pip just fine but when I try and install tensorflow for pypy using:

```
pypy -m pip install --upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/mac/tensorflow-0.9.0-py2-none-any.whl
```

I get error messages about how pypy doesn't play well with numpy. I already have numpy installed for pypy and it workes fine. I can do

```
pypy
>>>>import numpy
```

without any errors.

What am I doing wrong here? Is there a way to try and install tensorflow without it trying to install numpy? Has anyone done this before?

Comment: i don't think pypy is supported at the moment: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/252

Answer (score 0):

youcan use directly pip

example: Mac OS X, CPU only - py2

```
export TF_BINARY_URL=https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/mac/tensorflow-0.9.0-py2-none-any.whl

sudo pip install --upgrade $TF_BINARY_URL
```

If you need validate pip installation:

```
sudo easy_install pip
sudo easy_install --upgrade six
```

If you need info for other SO or more details you can see [here](http://export%20TF_BINARY_URL=https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/mac/tensorflow-0.9.0-py2-none-any.whl)